# Error Failed to get FirebaseApp instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore

Tags: firebase, ios, swift

Tengo este problema cuando intento iniciar mi app, me sale este error en la consola:

'The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization.'

' Failed to get FirebaseApp instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore'

En mi appDelegate ya tengo la funcion:
`FirebaseApp.configure()`

en un celular fisico, sale este error, Pero cuando inicio mi app en el simulador no me sale ningun error

Alguien tiene la solución?

Comment: Tienes actualizado todos los `pods`?

Comment: @Bicho Si, los tengo todos actualizados pero me sigue saliendo este error, actualmente estoy desarrollando dos apps con firebase y en ambas me sale este error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, solo tenía que inicializarlo antes de usarlo:

```
var firestore: Firestore!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firestore = Firestore.firestore()
}
```